# Dll to get list of open windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, dll, browser

I need to create a cross browser extension which can detect locally opened windows.
I came through JsWin which can call dll methods from javascript 
(http://0xef.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/calling-functions-in-dlls-from-javascript/) 
and was thinking of loading some windows dll or creating a class library to fetch windows list for the same. But it fails to do so...
Any other suggestion/guidance to achieve the same?

Comment: Javascript never has access to the clients computer for safety reasons. To do something like this, Java or Flash is required.

Comment: Thanks Alex.. In case of ActiveX, the implementation would then be restricted to Windows.. I need something like Snagot chrome extension, that can detect active windows to get local windows screenshot

Comment: The problem here with making it cross browser is that, as you pointed out ActiveX is Windows only and not everyone is found of installing / running a Java and Flash Applet. If you are making this for the masses I think you will have a hard time. But I'm not saying it's impossible.

Comment: Hi, so after some search, i found my requirements being fulfilled by WebRTC. It supports Chrome and Firefox for now. And can detect locally opened windows for screen capture/share.

Comment: Just by interest, I am aware of WebRTC being used as a communication "pipe line" so to speak, but to detect the locally opened window you are using some sort of standalone application to send the opened window to the client's browser via WebRTC, or how are you achieving this?